# How to set text in tag strong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder if I can set text or initial text in `<strong>` in javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// what should I do here?
}
</script>
<strong>Strong text</strong>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you do any research before asking?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Better to add a *class* or *id* to the html element as below :

**JS** :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".text").html("Your content here...");
});
```

**HTML** :

```
<strong class="text">Strong text</strong>
```

**Demo** : http://jsbin.com/cihilobe/1/

Comment: If using an ID, make sure to replace the ".text" with "#text"

Answer (score 6):

Give the element an id and this bit of vanilla javascript will do the job.

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "some text";
```

Or jquery

```
$("#id").text("some text");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use JQuery's tag selector to change the text :

```
$("strong").text("what ever you want")
```

Comment: This is not the right way. Since there may be a number of strong tags. Better to add an id or a unique class and then apply Jquery based on that class or id.

Comment: Yeah...I know that, but as per the question...this is a working solution.

Comment: Yes, it is a working solution. But our aim should be, to provide the best and apt solution.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham The OP didn't mention he want only 1 strong tag.. `How to set text in tag strong?`

Answer (score 0):

Use an id, since you may have multiple 'strong' tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#text').text('Strong text');
         });
      </script>
      <strong id="text"></strong>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an ID to the tag, then set its value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#target").html("Initial Text");
}
</script>
<strong id="target">Strong text</strong>
</body>
</html>
```